# Shortest common superstring

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-time

Given a list of strings `s_0, s_1, ..., s_n` find the shortest string `S` that contains each of `s_0, s_1, ..., s_n` as a [substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Substring).

*Examples*:

- `S('LOREM', 'DOLOR', 'SED', 'DO', 'MAGNA', 'AD', 'DOLORE')='SEDOLOREMAGNAD'`
- `S('ABCDE', 'BCD', 'C')='ABCDE'`

Write the shortest program (or function) that solves this problem. You can represent strings as arrays or lists of characters/integers if you want. Standard libraries are OK. For input/output you can use whatever is more convenient: STDIN/STDOUT, user prompt, parameter/return value of a function etc.

Performance is not critical - let's say, for an input of total length < 100 characters the result must be computed in < 10 second on average modern hardware.

Comment: +1 Nice question. I suggest you include some additional examples of expected outcomes so people can easily judge whether the submissions are able to handle a variety of cases.

Comment: How should input/output be handled? Should the result be printed or returned from a function?

Comment: so, no "for every string, if it contains all of ..., return it " is not a valid solution?

Comment: I doubt there's going to be an answer. This question might fit on [so] (without the code-golf part) quite well.

Comment: Is this problem in P?

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, <strike>170</strike> 153/157/159

Shortened thanks to some of [Baptiste's ideas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11630/7409).

```
from itertools import*
print min((reduce(lambda s,w:(w+s[max(i*(s[:i]==w[-i:])for i in range(99)):],s)[w in s],p)
for p in permutations(input())),key=len)
```

The second line break is not needed.

Input: `'LOREM', 'DOLOR', 'SED', 'DO', 'MAGNA', 'AD', 'DOLORE'`
Output: `SEDOLOREMAGNAD`

Even with long input strings, this runs in less than 2 seconds if there are at most 7 input strings (as is the case in the example given, which runs in <strike>1.7</strike> 1.5 seconds on my machine).  With 8 or more input strings, however, it takes more than 10 seconds, since the time complexity is `O(n!)`.

As Baptiste pointed out, `range(99)` needs to be replaced with `range(len(w))` if arbitrary input lengths should be supported (making the total length of the code 157 characters).  If empty input strings should be supported, it has to be changed to `range(len(w)+1)`.  I think `range(99)` works correctly for any total input length less than 200, though.

More tests:

```
>>> "AD", "DO", "DOLOR", "DOLORE", "LOREM", "MAGNA", "SED", "ORE",  "R"
SEDOLOREMAGNAD

>>> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
... xyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstu
... vwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'ZOOM', 'aZ', 'Za', 'ZA'
aZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZOOM
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica <strike>337 418</strike> 372

After trying unsuccessfully to implement using Mathematica's `LongestCommonSubsequencePositions`, I turned to pattern matching.

```
v=Length;
p[t_]:=Subsets[t,{2}];
f[w_]:=Module[{c,x,s=Flatten,r={{a___,Longest[y__]},{y__,b___}}:>{{a,y},{y,b},{y},{a,y,b}}},
c=p@w;
x=SortBy[Cases[s[{#/.r,(Reverse@#)/.r}&/@c,1],{_,_,_,_}],v[#[[3]]]&][[-1]];
Append[Complement[w,{x[[1]],x[[2]]}],x[[4]]]]

g[r_]:=With[{h=Complement[r,Cases[Join[p@r,p@Reverse@r],y_/;!StringFreeQ@@y:>y[[2]]]]},
FixedPoint[f,Characters/@h,v@h-1]<>""]
```

The pattern-matching rule,

```
r={{a___,Longest[y__]},{y__,b___}}:> {{a,y},{y,b},{y},{a,y,b}}},
```

takes an ordered pair of words (represented as lists of characters) and returns: (1) the words,`{a,y}` and `{y,b}` followed by (2) the common substring,`y`,  that links the end of one word with the beginning of the other word, and, finally, the combined word `{a,y,b}` that will replace the input words.  See Belisarius for a related example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/looking-for-longest-common-substring-solution

Three consecutive underscore characters signify that the element is a sequence of zero or more characters.

`Reverse` is employed later to ensure that both orders are tested.  Those pairs that share linkable letters are returned unchanged and ignored.

**Edit**:

The following removes from the list words that are  "buried" (i.e. fully contained) in another word, (in response to @flornquake's comment).

```
h=Complement[r,Cases[Join[p@r,p@Reverse@r],x_/;!StringFreeQ@@x:> x[[2]]]]
```

---

**Example**:

```
 {{"D", "O", "L", "O", "R", "E"}, {"L", "O", "R", "E", "M"}} /. r
```

returns

> {{"D", "O", "L", "O", "R", "E"}, {"L", "O", "R", "E", "M"}, {"L", "O",
>      "R", "E"}, {"D", "O", "L", "O", "R", "E", "M"}}

---

**Usage**

```
g[{"LOREM", "ORE", "R"}]

AbsoluteTiming[g[{"AD", "DO", "DOLOR", "DOLORE", "LOREM", "MAGNA", "SED", "ORE",  "R"}]]
```

> "LOREM"
>
> {0.006256, "SEDOLOREMAGNAD"}

Comment: Does this work for input `"LOREM", "ORE", "R"`?

Comment: (I.e., does it produce the correct output `"LOREM"`?)

Comment: @flornquake.  Nice catch.  I addressed it in the current version.  I hope I haven't missed any other cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <strike>203</strike> <strike>187</strike> 200

```
from itertools import permutations as p
def n(c,s=''):
 for x in c:s+=x[next((i+1 for i,l in [(j,x[:j+1])for j in range(len(x))][::-1]if s.endswith(l)),0):]
 return s
print min(map(n,p(input())),key=len)
```

Input: `['LOREM', 'DOLOR', 'SED', 'DO', 'MAGNA', 'AD', 'DOLORE']`
Output: `SEDOLOREMAGNAD`

**Edit**

Using `reduce` and some dirty import trickery, I can reduce this further (and to one line only!):

```
print min((reduce(lambda a,x:a+x[next((i+1 for i,l in [(j,x[:j+1])for j in range(len(x))][::-1]if a.endswith(l)),0):],P,'')for P in __import__('itertools').permutations(input())),key=len)
```

**Edit 2**

As flornquake noted, this gives incorrect results when one word is contained in another. The fix for this adds another 13 chars:

```
print min((reduce(lambda a,x:a+(x[next((i+1 for i,l in [(j,x[:j+1])for j in range(len(x))][::-1]if a.endswith(l)),0):],'')[x in a],P,'')for P in __import__('itertools').permutations(input())),key=len)
```

Here's the cleaned up version:

```
from itertools import permutations

def solve(*strings):
    """
    Given a list of strings, return the shortest string that contains them all.
    """
    return min((simplify(p) for p in permutations(strings)), key=len)

def prefixes(s):
    """
    Return a list of all the prefixes of the given string (including itself),
    in ascending order (from shortest to longest).
    """
    return [s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s))]
    return [(i,s[:i+1]) for i in range(len(s))][::-1]

def simplify(strings):
    """
    Given a list of strings, concatenate them wile removing overlaps between
    successive elements.
    """
    ret = ''
    for s in strings:
        if s in ret:
            break
        for i, prefix in reversed(list(enumerate(prefixes(s)))):
            if ret.endswith(prefix):
                ret += s[i+1:]
                break
        else:
            ret += s
    return ret

print solve('LOREM', 'DOLOR', 'SED', 'DO', 'MAGNA', 'AD', 'DOLORE')
```

It's possible to shave off a few characters at the cost of theoretical correctness by using `range(99)` instead of `range(len(x))` (credits to flornquake for thinking of this one).

Comment: If you're willing to sacrifice correctness then you might as well use the greedy approach or the polynomial approximation factor of 2 approach.

Comment: Nice solution! You need to check if new words are already in the superstring, though: `'LOREM', 'ORE', 'R'` incorrectly produces the output `LOREMORER`.

Comment: @flornquake Good catch. I managed to fix it but it adds 13 characters.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 144 chars

```
S=lambda A,s:min(S(A-set([a]),s+a[i:])for a in A for i in range(len(a)+1)if i==0 or s[-i:]==a[:i])if A else(len(s),s)
T=lambda L:S(set(L),'')[1]
```

`S` takes a set of words `A` that still need placing and a string `s` containing words placed so far.  We pick a remaining word `a` from `A` and overlap it from `0` to `len(a)` characters with the end of `s`.

Takes only about 0.15 seconds on the given example.

Comment: Really nice! But like some other solutions, this doesn't work for input like `['LOREM', 'ORE', 'R']`.
I've taken the liberty to fix that and golf your solution some more:  `S=lambda A,s='':A and min((S(A-{a},(s+a[max(i*(s[-i:]==a[:i])for i in range(len(a))):],s)[a in s])for a in A),key=len)or s` (a second line is not needed).  Usage: `S({'LOREM', 'DOLOR', 'SED', 'DO', 'MAGNA', 'AD', 'DOLORE'})` returns `'SEDOLOREMAGNAD'`.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 121

```
import Data.List
a p []=[(length p,p)]
a p s=[r|w<-s,t<-tails w,isInfixOf w$p++t,r<-a(p++t)(s\\[w])]
s=snd.minimum.a ""
```

Minus two if the function doesn't need to be bound to a name